# SQL 1064 Syntax Error using a JDBC prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Basestations VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,"
               + "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";                  


PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(query);

prep.setInt(1, profile.getNetworkId());
prep.setInt(2, profile.getBaseStationId());
prep.setInt(8, profile.getLoadLevel());
prep.setInt(11, profile.getPositionX());
prep.setInt(12, profile.getPositionY());
prep.setInt(13, profile.getPort());

prep.setDouble(3, profile.getSignalStrength());
prep.setDouble(4, profile.getFrequency());
prep.setDouble(6, profile.getMaxBitrate());
prep.setDouble(7, profile.getGuaranteedBitrate());
prep.setDouble(10, profile.getRange());

prep.setString(5, profile.getNetworkType());
prep.setString(9, profile.getProvider());
prep.setString(14, profile.getCharging());

prep.setBoolean(15, true);


prep.executeUpdate(query);
```

and i am getting:

INFO: SQL Exception:
INFO: State  : 42000
INFO: Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1
INFO: Error  : 1064

what could be wrong?

Comment: It would help to know the values being set when you get the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're passing an string representing an invalid SQL statement to the `executeUpdate()` method when you don't need to. Try just doing `prep.executeUpdate();`.

Answer (score 2):

In your last line you don't need pass the variable query.

So change

```
 prep.executeUpdate(query);
```

For:

```
 prep.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

The main error is here:

```
 // incorrect
 prep.executeUpdate(query);

 // correct
 prep.executeUpdate();
```

But please try to put your SQL in the following form:

```
UPDATE table_name(field1, field2, field3) VALUES(?, ? ,?)
```

This will prevent your code from breaking if there is an update to the table.